Call function from dynamic library with changing signature?
Say I have hello1.c
char *greeting = "Hello, Version 1";

char *greet(void) {
  return greeting;
}

and hello2.c
int greeting = 42;

int greet(void) {
    return greeting;
}

My host.c looks like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LIBHELLO_SO "libhello.so"

void load_and_call_greet() {
    // Open the shared library
    void *dynamic_lib = dlopen(LIBHELLO_SO, RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!dynamic_lib) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        return;
    }

    // Define a function pointer for the function we want to call
    char *(*greet)(void);

    // Get the function from the shared library
    greet = (char *(*)(void)) dlsym(dynamic_lib, "greet");

    // Check for errors
    char *error;
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
        dlclose(dynamic_lib); // Close the library before exiting
        return;
    }

    // Call the function and print the result
    printf("%s\n", greet());

    // Close the shared library
    dlclose(dynamic_lib);
}

int main() {
    while (1) {
        load_and_call_greet();
        sleep(5);  // Wait for 5 seconds before reloading the library
    }
    return 0;
}

Then, I compile and run host file and without terminating host file I want to swap my dynamic library to the new signature (from hello1.c to hello2.c):
/ ./host
/ prints "Hello, Version 1" every 5 seconds
/ in another terminal re-compile libhello.so but use `hello2.c` as source file rather than `hello1.c`
/ expected result: ./host prints 42
/ actual result: './host terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

Is it possible to change host.c code to load function with changing signature from dynamic library?
I tried couple of approaches with ChatGPT but it gives SIGSEGV (Address boundary error).

"Is it possible to change host.c code to load function with changing signature from dynamic library" It's not clear exactly what you mean by this.  Can you update your code to illustrate what you're trying to do?  Also, are hello1.c and hello2.c both included in your library, or just one?

C doesn't preserve types once the code has been built. There's no way to know the arguments or return type for any function in libraries you load.

@Someprogrammerdude makes sense, is it possible to call with one signature, then catch error if any and try with another?

@drets no that's not an option. You'll most likely get undefined behaviour.

This is unfortunately a problem that can't be solved by code. This has to be solved by design and specifications and documentation and unit-testing and code-reviews.

You can't recompile just one side of a function call and expect anything to work. If you change the signature of the function, you need to recompile both ends; they need to agree on what is being passed in and out, that's the entire point of function signatures - they are a contract between two points in your code that tell the call site how to setup the call, and how to receive results. If they don't agree, they can't correctly communicate.

@user229044 I kinda got the point but if I know that guest functions can have 2 signatures: this or that, why it's not possible? :) it's also sorta contract.

@drets Sorry, are you asking about function overloading?  There is no function overloading in C. You can't have both greet(int) and greet(const char*) the way you can in C++, and even in C++ you can't overload only by return type. If you're asking about why you can't dynamically link against a function without knowing its return type in your code, that's just the way C, and most statically typed languages, work. If you want to be able to return arbitrary types then you need to wrap them in something that caries type information, ex a struct with enum type and void* data.

The syntax of the language does not allow you to express functions that return integers sometimes, and strings other times. Some type systems do support this, for example union/intersection types in TypeScript, but C does not.

@user229044, "The syntax of the language does not allow you to express functions that return integers sometimes, and strings other times." is technically true, and true in the sense relevant to this question, but of course a C function can return a union that has both an int and a char * member.  But of course, that's still just one return type -- the union -- about which function and callers must agree.

[If, in C++], you may be talking about a generic function, overloaded function, or subclass. For some ideas how to do this in C, see my answer: Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C

This isn't possible, as calling a function through an invalid pointer triggers undefined behavior in your code.
The closest you can do is to keep a set signature and return a pointer to a known structure that contains a void * and information about what it points to.
For example:
hello.h:
#define TYPE_INT 1
#define TYPE_CHARP 2

struct hello {
    int type;
    void *value;
};

hello1.c:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hello.h"

char *greeting = "Hello, Version 1";

struct hello *greet(void) {
  struct hello *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
  p->type = TYPE_CHARP;
  p->value = strdup(greeting);
  return greeting;
}

hello2.c:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hello.h"

int greeting = 42;

struct hello *greet(void) {
  struct hello *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
  p->type = TYPE_INT;
  p->value = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *p->value = greeting;
  return greeting;
}

Then to call it:
// either define explicitly or include hello.h
#define TYPE_INT 1
#define TYPE_CHARP 2

struct hello {
    int type;
    void *value;
};

void load_and_call_greet() {
    // either define explicitly or include hello.h
    #define TYPE_INT 1
    #define TYPE_CHARP 2

    struct hello {
        int type;
        void *value;
    };

    // Open the shared library
    void *dynamic_lib = dlopen(LIBHELLO_SO, RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!dynamic_lib) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        return;
    }

    // Define a function pointer for the function we want to call
    struct hello *(*greet)(void);

    // Get the function from the shared library
    greet = (struct hello *(*)(void)) dlsym(dynamic_lib, "greet");

    // Check for errors
    char *error;
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
        dlclose(dynamic_lib); // Close the library before exiting
        return;
    }

    // Call the function and print the result
    struct hello *result = greet();
    if (result->type == TYPE_INT) {
        print("%d\n", *((int *)result->value));
    } else if (result->type == TYPE_CHARP) {
        printf("%s\n", *((char *)result->value));
    }
    free(result->value);
    free(result);

    // Close the shared library
    dlclose(dynamic_lib);
    char *(*greet)(void);

    // Get the function from the shared library
    greet = (char *(*)(void)) dlsym(dynamic_lib, "greet");
}

